# IE10 not centering tables

Tags: html-table, alignment, internet-explorer-10

I have a table, that is centered in Chrome, Firefox, even IE9, but not in IE10. I read, that Microsoft decided to kill the table layout, but please, give a workaround, I cannot rewrite the code, just for IE10!

Comment: you cannot rewrite your code? the don't ask if you can't do anything ^^

Comment: search for some ie10 fixes